# Comparing Characters in an If Statement

Tags: c

I started learning C two days ago and I ran into a problem while working on an assignment.  We are meant to take a list of characters from a char array and shorten it through counting consecutive chars and replacing them with numbers. Say "aaaabbbbbccccc" to "a4b5c5".  This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    char letters[999];
    char newString[100];
    char counter[100];

    printf("Please input a string: ");
    fgets(letters, sizeof(letters), stdin);

    int i;
    int count = 1;
    int end = 0;

    for (i=0; i < strlen(letters); i++) {
        if (letters[i] != letters[i+1] || letters[i+1] == '\0') {
            newString[end] = letters[i];
            end++;
            printf("CHECK HERE");
            count = 1;
        } else if (letters[i] == letters[i+1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("%s", newString);
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason this goes through the first if statement an incorrect amount of times, and I cannot figure out why. Does it have to do with the character equality statement? The output turns out to be

```
CHECK HERECHECK HERECHECK HERE
[letters in newString]
```

Comment: The is an error at line 18, you have `end++` without `;`

Comment: Have you written the string teminator `'\0'` to `newString`, or is it hidden in the `i+1` manipulations? There should be `newString[end] = '\0';` before printing it.

Comment: And The counted value is not output. Also If there is no repetition, the output string (`newString`) is too small.

Comment: @WeatherVane I assumed that '\0' is automatically added to the end of a character array?

Comment: Only when it is initialised, such as `char str[] = "abc";`

Comment: edited original post to show the output I was receiving

Comment: Minor niggle: 'for(i=0; i<strlen(letters); i++){' calls strlen() every time round the loop.

Comment: ... and compiler warning *'<': signed/unsigned mismatch*

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with comparing characters like you have done. Your code doesn't however produce the destination string per your requirement. The count isn't loaded into the new-string.

```
if(letters[i] != letters[i+1] || letters[i+1] == '\0') {
    newString [end] = letters [i];
    end++; 
    newString [end] = '0' + count; /* Converting integer count to ascii char */
    end++;
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to null-terminate the new string.
**PS.:** You need to specially handle the count if it is > 1 digit (load byte-by-byte).

Comment: thanks, that worked! what should I do if the count is greater than 1 digit though?

Comment: Think about how you can extract each digit of a number, convert it to its ascii equivalent as shown above. Hint: think division & modulo operators.